# Bootstrap list view like jqm

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, javascript

I am looking to recreate some native mobile list functions like list view, list view filter/search, and complex list view.

Here is an example from jquery mobile.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-formatting.html

Does anyone have a lib or extension for bootstrap to mimic some of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Does that helps? 
http://www.iui-js.org/download

It is for iphone applications!

Comment: It helps but I'm targeting mobile not just ios. I'm also needing something friendly to bootstrap and a responsive media