# Mobile javascript framework with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, iui

In one of my website I use Twitter Bootstrap 2.3. I love its responsive behaviour, media queries in mobile devices. But it lacks of mobile features (especially [linked listviews](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/widgets/listviews/#list-linked)) So I need to use a framework that would handle mobile version of my website.

After some research I found that jquery mobile, sensa touch, jqtouch, iui, mobilize.js, zepto are possible candidates.

What would be your recommendation for a javascript framework/plugin for mobile pages, that would work well with twitter bootstrap ?

Possible related questions:
[Bootstrap list view like jqm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093345/bootstrap-list-view-like-jqm)
[twitter-bootstrap vs jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242012/twitter-bootstrap-vs-jquery-mobile)
[Using Bootstrap with jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599110/using-bootstrap-with-jquery-mobile?rq=1)

Comment: For clarification, are you wondering about Bootstrap for everyone, and Bootstrap + jQuery Mobile (or other alternatives) for viewers with mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

Also read this: [Twitter Bootstrap Navbar: [Left Button -— Center Text -— Right Button]? II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383644/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-left-button-center-text-right-button-ii/17383645)

I think i should be possible to build a mobile interface with Twitter's Bootstrap (3). And yes you're right (linked) listviews will miss. Maybe check http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group first. Of course you will need to write some code to handle the actions.

Other points to consider: Navigation and page structure. Frameworks like jQuery mobile serve more pages on one url, see: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html while sencha use a MVC approach. Consider http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs (or http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy maybe) to mimic such structures.

Other examples, see: [How to make a JS horizontal content slide from px to % responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176776/how-to-make-a-js-horizontal-content-slide-from-px-to-responsive/18177433) a nice interface with TB by [@boblet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318704/boblet) which adopt to mobile very well now: http://bootply.com/73715. [David Panzarella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1914389/david-panzarella) started a clean mobile navbar with icons:  [Bootstrap 3 RC2 Navbar with Multiple Collapses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269043/bootstrap-3-rc2-navbar-with-multiple-collapses#comment26813758_18269043) And a alternative mobile navigation stucture can be found here: [Toggle sidebar on mobile device with Twitter Bootstrap 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871718/toggle-sidebar-on-mobile-device-with-twitter-bootstrap-2-x)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to mess up with Bootstrap and other several frameworks together then make sure you have sound knowledge in jQuery, JavaScript, CSS.

Each framework has their own way of enforcing styles etc, so if you are to combines multiple platforms together, you will often encounter issues such as the expected style from expected framework is not being applied.

I’d recommend you to stick with jQuery Mobile. jQuery Mobile 1.3 has great deal of Responsive design concepts. In the release notes itself they’ve mentioned that they are working hard to support Responsive designs. Read the official [documentation provided by jQuery Mobile](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/intro/rwd.php). This will give you a good head start.

Disclaimer : I have used only Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery Mobile. But I’ve heard from people other Mobile frameworks are not as flexible as jQuery Mobile. Also remember Sencha touch is very fast compare to jQuery Mobile but bit difficult for absolute beginners to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend iUI since i'm working on it (eh eh) and because it's more or less an empty canvas you can "draw" whatever you want on.
JQuery Mobile or  Sencha are nice, but they come with dozens or buttons & UI elements you might not need for a website. It's even getting a mess if you want to give a custom look to your mobile website when everything is predefined.

afaik, Zepto is only a lighter JQuery, so that wouldn't solve you linked listviews issue that much...

Please, give a try to my iUI v2 project, Emy, that you can try here:
http://www.emy-library.org/demos/
Still a few bugs to fix but i'm damn close to the initial release. Big difference compare to iUI are HTML5 syntax, custom animations, full documentation and WindowsPhone support.
http://www.emy-library.org/documentation/1.0/getting-started.html

Cheers!