# how to make bootstrap off canvas nav overlap content instead of move it

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I like the off canvas feature that bootstrap 3 has: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/. However, for one of my projects i'd like it to overlap the content rather than move the content to the side. Is this possible? If so how?

Here's what i mean by overlapping:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**update** (based on your comment and new sketch)

See: http://bootply.com/78559

**html**:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="background-color:lightgreen;height:500px;">
        Content

        <button id="navigator">Show Nav</button>
    </div>
    <div class="sidenav col-sm-3" style="background-color:red;height:100px;">Nav</div>
</div>


  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
  </footer>

</div><!--/.container-->
```

**css**:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) 
{ 

    .sidenav
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        height: 0px;
        width: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        left:100%; 
        padding:0;
    }

    .sidenav.on
    {    

        width:50%;
        left:50%;
        -webkit-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
        transition: all 2s ease 0s;

    }   

}
```

javascript:

```
 $('#navigator').click(function(){$('div.sidenav').toggleClass('on');});
```

--

Yes, see: http://bootply.com/77207

The off canvas feature is not a default feature of bootstrap.
This demo shows what you can do with Bootstrap, css, mediaqueries and javascript (jQuery).

1) media queries hide the sidebar when the screen width is below 768px (css a negative right position)
2) clicking the button adds the class .active to the content (including the sidebar)
3) css sets the position of the content with class .active to the left with ... % (positive right position) the content hide (outside the viewport) and the navbar become visible.
4) the effect of show / hide is done with CSS3 transitions http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

In the original example the content swift 50%, change this to 100% (or a little more) will give the effect of overlap.

Maybe also see:
[Toggle sidebar on mobile device with Twitter Bootstrap 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871718/toggle-sidebar-on-mobile-device-with-twitter-bootstrap-2-x) (easy to migrate to TB3)

Comment: in your example, the content slides to the left to make room for the sidebar. I was wanting the sidebar to slide "on top" of the content

Comment: again, pretty much the same thing, it just "hides" the content, instead of overlapping it

Comment: what's your definition of overlapping? could provide a sketch or example?

Answer (score 0):

simply set the the overflow to visible in the canvas body class
like this:

your content

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#Sidebar" aria-controls="Sidebar">
        toggle ofcanvas
    </button>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="Sidebar" aria-labelledby="SidebarLabel">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
          <h3 class="offcanvas-title" id="SidebarLabel">Clothes</h3>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body overflow-visible">
          <div>
            <h4>Categories</h4>
            <p>You're one stop shop for all your clothing needs!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown mt-3 d-flex flex-column">
           <div class="btn-group dropend my-2">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
               Men
             </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Shirts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Pants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Shoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Underwear</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Socks</a></li>         
                </ul>   
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group dropend my-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Women
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Shirts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Pants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Shoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Underwear</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Socks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dresses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Skirts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group dropend my-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Kids
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Shirts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Pants</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Shoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Underwear</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Socks</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group dropend my-2">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Sale!</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form action="#" method="POST" class="my-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="min" class="form-label">min Price</label>
                <input type="number" name="min" id="min" class="form-control">
                <label for="max" class="form-label">max Price</label>
                <input type="number" name="max" id="max" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group my-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```