# Create sticky side navbar in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create Sticky Side Navbar on Left side in My Web Site. & I'm Using Bootstrap 3 RC2. I don't know How to create it.

Comment: wut u tried so far ??

Answer (score 11):

You need to define the CSS for when the sidebar becomes fixed...

For example,

```css
#sidebar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top:25px;
    width:228px;
  }
```

Here is a **working example**: http://bootply.com/73864

Answer (score 8):

The sticky navbar you are refereing to is possible thanks to the affix plugin. You can [view the bootstrap documentation on this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

This [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ykJ8/) contains a working sticky sidebar (make the result window larger to see it work properly). Read on to create the same sidebar.

**1. Create html for your sidebar.** For this example we will use bootstraps nav-pills within a well.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="well bs-sidebar affix" id="sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!--well bs-sidebar affix-->
  </div> <!--col-sm-3-->
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <p>Main body content goes here</p>
  </div> <!--col-sm-9-->
</div> <!--row-->
```

**2. Invoke the affix plugin in your js file**

```
$('#sidebar').affix({
  offset: {
    top: $('header').height()
  }
});
```

You need to replace 'header' with whatever will be above the the sidebar. If you are using a bootstrap navbar and it is directly above the sidebar, replace 'header' with the class you are using for the navbar, for example:

```
top: $('.navbar navbar-default').height()
```

**3. Add css for affix class**

CSS for non-responsive layout

```
.bs-sidebar.affix {
  width: 263px;
  top: 25px;
}
```

CSS for responsive layout

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bs-sidebar.affix {
    width: 158px;
    top: 25px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .bs-sidebar.affix {
    width: 213px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .bs-sidebar.affix {
    width: 263px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default Navbar of Twitter's Bootstrap 3 is horizontal. There are four types of it, default, static top and fixed top and bottom, see the example section of this page: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started

But of course you can use Twitter's Bootstrap 3 to build a (left)side navigation.
Please first read the Docs, it contain many examples. Make a sketch of you idea, try to code it with the examples. Ask questions here for troubleshooting of your code.
Start at the affix (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) and the nav section (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) first maybe.

Maybe also check: [how to make bootstrap off canvas nav overlap content instead of move it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422699/how-to-make-bootstrap-off-canvas-nav-overlap-content-instead-of-move-it/18453969)