# Please help I need a sticky responsive sidebar

Tags: sidebar, sticky

I need a sticky responsive sidebar like this sites https://www.localbanya.com/ &
https://redmart.com/ please help I was searching it from weeks but had no success. And it will be helpful if it's bootstrap compatible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a sticky left sidebar menu using bootstrap 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681895/how-to-create-a-sticky-left-sidebar-menu-using-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Here is another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572313/create-sticky-side-navbar-in-bootstrap-3-0) for you

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Semantic-UI's sidebar](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples). It works just like bootstrap.
Here is the html:

```
<body>
  <div class="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
    <a class="item">
      1
    </a>
    <a class="item">
     2
    </a>
    <a class="item">
     3
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="pusher">
    <!-- Site content !-->
  </div>
</body>
```

And to activate the toggle using javascript:

```
$('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
```