# Trying to show an Off Canvas over the current content - CSS - HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some off canvas content that I am showing with a basic slide animation.  The `sidebar` just slides in from the right side.  When the content slides in, it pushes my current content to the left, and I just want the content to be displayed over the content on the page.  Here is my html:

```
<div class="container-full header-offset">
  <div class="row-offcanvas">
    <div class="row">
      <div  id="encounterList" class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8"></div>
      <div  id="chatContainer" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 sidebar-offcanvas"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the important css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: right .3s ease-in;
    -most-transition: right .3s ease-in;
    transition: right .3s ease-in;
  }
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    right: -80%;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
  }
  &.active {
    right: 80%;
  }
}
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Can you set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make bootstrap off canvas nav overlap content instead of move it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422699/how-to-make-bootstrap-off-canvas-nav-overlap-content-instead-of-move-it)