# Bootstrap 3.0 Sliding Menu from left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, slidingmenu, mmenu

I've implemented a sliding menu from left to right in my bootstrap 3.0 website using [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/). However, the performances in Android (samsung galaxy) are not ideal. 
I also have a default collapsing menu (nav- dropdown) which perform much better.

I was wondering if any of you guys has a solution to improve the left menu ? Is there any Bootstrap 3.0 component that would do that and be as smooth as the default dropdown ? (couldn't find anything mentioned in the doc) ? or any other recommendation ?

Comment: Look to http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871718/toggle-sidebar-on-mobile-device-with-twitter-bootstrap-2-x maybe

Comment: Thanks buddy. I ended up using offcanvas indeed. Just few performance issues on other phones than iphones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootsrap 3 and mmenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280789/bootsrap-3-and-mmenu)

Answer (score 14):

I believe that although javascript is an option here, you have a smoother animation through forcing hardware accelerate with CSS3. You can achieve this by setting the following CSS3 properties on the moving div:

```
div.hardware-accelarate {
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
          -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
             transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

I've made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GGQLn519tPCrqjwHER4W?p=preview) setup for ya'll to test and tweak...

Answer (score 10):

Probably late but here is a plugin that can do the job : http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/

Also v2 can use mobile gesture such as swipe ;)

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Link still accessible with archive.org : https://web.archive.org/web/20200109020357/http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/