# JavaScript framework that emulates jQueryMobile's pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, javascript-framework

My favorite part of jQuery Mobile is the ability to create multiple pages in a single HTML request by  using `data-role="page"`. However, I'd prefer to use Bootstrap for everything else -- styling, widgets, etc.

I'm wondering if there is a more lightweight JS framework that *just* implements the pages functionality of jQuery Mobile, or if I will have to roll my own.

Comment: Jqtouch http://jqtjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Maybe consider http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs also. Tabs seems to have the functionality you are looking for.

See also:

- [Twitter Bootstrap Navbar: [Left Button -— Center Text -— Right Button]? II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383644/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-left-button-center-text-right-button-ii/)
- [Toggle sidebar on mobile device with Twitter Bootstrap 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871718/toggle-sidebar-on-mobile-device-with-twitter-bootstrap-2-x/)